# Android actionbar how to add supporting library v7 appcompat for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I followed every steps in [Android - ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to add action bar.
I extend the activity from ActionBarActivity:
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity

I need to add appcompat v7 support library as in [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html): In "Adding libraries with resources", eclipse section. The last steps:

"Add the library to your application project:

1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
2. In the Library pane, click Add.
3. Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
4. In the properties window, click OK. "

Step 2 is where I can't find the Library pane. How can I add the library to my project?

Comment: For working with the support library you might find this blog entry helpful.  It also allows for you to attach the source which I find helpful to understanding the steps.  http://right-handed-monkey.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-run-android-support-library.html

Answer (score 39):

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[image]

Comment: If you can post the screenshot of your setup and/or give more detail, I can try and help

Comment: Piyey, if you are running under Windows and your project always becomes marked by red cross and not as on screen above, try locating both (main and library) projects on one partition.

Comment: styanton, thank you. You have no idea how frustrated I was getting before seeing this comment. Thank you so much haha

Answer (score 11):

Following are the steps:

1. Paste the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` that you have downloaded in `libs` folder of your project.
2. Right click on your project, select `Build Path` -> `Configure build path`.
3. Select `Library Tab` then `Add Jar` option and browse your recently added `v7` jar and click `OK`

that's it :)

Comment: This is the procedure for support libraries without resources. But as v7-appcompat contains resources you really need to follow the section "Adding libraries with resources" on http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html which is more involved.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

1. Eclipse -> Import -> Existing Android Code into workspace.
2. Add ~/android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat to your Eclipse workspace.
3. Right click on the project in Eclipse and select properties.
4. Select Android -> Library -> Add.
5. Select appcompatv7 project and Save.

Use import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar to import Action bar in activities and fragments.

Answer (score 3):

The library pane shows up if you select android first in the left hand list.  It should then be at the bottom of the right hand section of the properties window, underneath the Project Build Target section.

Comment: Thanks. That's it. The document should really say select android in the left menu first. Then you can see the Library pane.

Comment: For those with many API's downloaded you need to select Android in the left menu as said and then scroll down. I have every API installed and the long list can make it seem like it's the only thing in the pane.

Answer (score 2):

This is the the solution I've used to solve that problem.

1. Make sure that you've installed already the following libraries ***Android Support Library, Android Support Repository and Google Repository*** by checking in the ***Extra*** folder by openning the **Android SDK Manager** in eclipse.
2. Create an ***Android Sample Project*** then choose the ***appcompact_v7*** library.
3. Close the project you've just created, restart Eclipse and create now a new ***Android Application project***.

Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In may case this works:

In "android-support-v7-appcompat" project:

```
-Delete “android-support-v7-appcompat” from Package explorer.
-Import again and check “Copy into workspace”
-In Properties -> Android -> in Project build target, uncheck Android 2.2 and check Android 4.1.2
-In Java build path, uncheck if you have any .jar library, and uncheck the Dependence
```

In other hand, the project that uses “android-support-v7-appcompat”

```
in Properties -> Android add the library, but uncheck "IsLibrary”.
-In Android -> Project build target check Android 4.0.
-In "Java Build Path" -> Order and Export -> Unchecked the .jar library
-Finally do a “Project -> Clean” both projects
```

Answer (score 0):

following the latest(2014/5/19) [document](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), the second step is:

> In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.

then, you will see the library pane on the right side of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Install Android support Repository
3. Go to F:--\Android Setup\android-sdk-21 version\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs
4. Copy android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
5. Paste this .jar in Your's Project Lib Folder

Set and change AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```