# How to make App Compatible with Froyo and above

Tags: android

I am writing a Church Application in which i am using Swipe-able Tabs using this [tutorial](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html)

but i want my app to support Froyo and above !

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.learn2crack.tab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.learn2crack.tab.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the compatibility library and make   `android:minSdkVersion="8"`. Be sure that all the imports refer to the support library

Answer (score 0):

You can use supported library and use `android:minSdkVersion="8"`

this is link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903778/1332870

Answer (score 0):

Modify your uses-sdk with the following.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```