# Android application launch error with Unfortunately has stopped

Tags: android

I created a new Android application project in Eclipse on Mac. I set it up Android 4.4.2 sdk.

When I installed this sample project in the physical Nexus 7 Tablet, it throws the following launching error . I have not added anything yet in this project, it is just a sample project created as it is.

**Unfortunately has stopped**

```
04-13 00:16:05.395: W/dalvikvm(6761): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/myfinaltest/MainActivity; (2)
04-13 00:16:05.395: W/dalvikvm(6761): Link of class 'Lcom/example/myfinaltest/MainActivity;' failed
04-13 00:16:05.395: D/AndroidRuntime(6761): Shutting down VM
04-13 00:16:05.395: W/dalvikvm(6761): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415bcba8)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761): Process: com.example.myfinaltest, PID: 6761
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfinaltest/com.example.myfinaltest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myfinaltest.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfinaltest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myfinaltest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myfinaltest.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfinaltest-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myfinaltest-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-13 00:16:05.395: E/AndroidRuntime(6761):     ... 11 more
```

Code:

```
package com.example.myfinaltest;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfinaltest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

For, values/styles.xml and values-v11/styles.xml and values-v14/styles.xml

same values for all 3 xml's, however I commented App theme, because I was seeing errors building with Appcompat libs.

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>
-->

    <!-- Application theme. 
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
-->
</resources>
```

Comment: Post `AndroidManifest.xml`. What does your `values/styles.xml` look like?

Comment: I updated AndroidManifest and styles data

Comment: I know why this happening. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `AppCompat` and extending `ActionBarActivity` you need to specify the correct theme.

### `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfinaltest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> <!-- You need a theme -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### `values/styles.xml`:

You can delete all of them **except** `values/styles.xml`.

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I am having building error with Appcompat: [2015-04-13 01:48:04 - MyFinalTest] Workspace/MyFinalTest/res/values/styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: I see you are using `Eclipse`, right-click your project and make sure `AppCompat` is added as a build resource.

Comment: Do I have set in here, Right click Properties->Java build path->Libraries? From where can i choose appcompat?

Comment: `AppCompat` is in your "Android SDK" folder on your machine. Why have you not made the switch to Android Studio? This is all done for you in Android Studio.

Comment: I am using Mac 10.10 Yosemite, Android studio doesn't supported.

Comment: Could you please give me the steps to add appcompat?

Comment: I am using Android Studio right now on Mac. Here is the download link for Mac: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

Comment: Stella, read my comments. I just told you how to add AppCompat.

Comment: Android studio supported only upto Mac 10.9

Comment: Stella, why are you fighting with me? I am using Mac OSX 10.10.2 Yosimite. I am trying to help you. Here is the exact link if you want to download: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/1.1.0/android-studio-ide-135.1740770-mac.dmg.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm not fighting, Sorry, Apologies..Thanks, I'll download it..Meanwhile I am trying to set it up in eclipse as well. I am trying to add appcompat like this, right click project Properties->Java build path->Libraries->Add external JARs. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You are very close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903521/android-actionbar-how-to-add-supporting-library-v7-appcompat.

Comment: According to mentioned in that link you shared, I tried importing appcompat project into workspace first, it throws error in this appcompat project in res/values-v21/stylebase.xml file at this line, <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" , "Error retrieving parent item: No resource found that matches given name android.widget.material.actionbutton'

Comment: Please Google for help. See the official docs here: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-without-res

Comment: I am installing Android studio as you suggested. I need to create one screen where I'll have to play an audio file from my server. This app should work on both Phone and Tab as well. If you have any sample playing audio from server, kindly share me the sample link and also sample link for having screen to work with phone and tab as well.

Comment: I have answered your original question. This is now becoming off-topic and turning into another question.

Comment: Sure..Just asked some help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75071/discussion-between-jared-burrows-and-stella).

Answer (score 1):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml in order to see whether your activity is defined as follows.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfinaltest.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

The package name might not be "com.example.myfinaltest" in your case.

Comment: No, It is not working. I have pasted the data there in the AndroidManifest.