# Android build path

Tags: java, android

[image]

Hi ,This is my first android application , by creating the package , I had a lot of build path errors. and I do not know how to solve,please help me

Comment: this is caused because you didn't add appcompat to your project
, follow the instructions described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903521/android-actionbar-how-to-add-supporting-library-v7-appcompat-for-eclipse#answer-17903778)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure its the "appcompat_v7", which is automatically generated in eclipse when setting up an android project. It imports unnecessary features and causes a bunch of build errors.

1. Delete "appcompat_v7" folder
2. - go to your MainActivity
   - Delete the import "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity";
   - change "MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity" to  "MainActivity extends Activity"
3. - add import android.app.Activity;
   - add import android.os.Bundle;
   - add import android.view.Menu;
   - add import android.view.MenuItem;
4. go to res folder and then go to your values folder...delete styles.xml
5. delete values-v11 folder
6. delete values-v14 folder
7. go to menu folder, and click on main.xml...go to "item" tag and delete app:showAsAction="never"
8. go to AndroidManifest.xml...go to "application" tag...delete  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
9. go to project at the top...clean and build...you should have no more errors.

Comment: Thanks Andrew EL-Masry ,I followed the steps but still eclipse signal errors , this kind of errors : R cannot resolved to a variable MainActivity.  thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I assume you are using eclipse...did you click project at the top, and then clean and build?

Comment: Yes Andrew , i did that , but it it doesn't solve the R  error :(

Comment: are there any errors in your xml files? no errors in values folder or AndroidManifest?

Comment: Andrew , i've solve it .it is ultimately a problem of  sdk , i update it and now there is no errors :) . thanks for your help Anrew