# How can I solve the 'PagerSlidingTabStrip cannot be resolved to a type' error in my code?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse and I need to use the Sliding tabs with PagerSlidingTabStrip in my android activity. What must be the solution?

Comment: Use the official Android Design support library

Comment: Still the same error. :(

Comment: What does it mean "Still same error" ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a library and sample [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)
You can import lib and appcombat_v7 to use it.

[How to import appcombat_v7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24595123/3832212)

Comment: I'll go and try this one. Thanks!