# AppCompatActivity crashing the app in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, appcompatactivity, android-appcompat

I'm creating an app in **Eclipse** and now I want to Use **appcompat library** in my project.
I have imported the library successfully and it is working fine when I extends some Activity with AppCompatActivity.
The Problem is, when I run the app and My Application Launch that Activity which is extended by AppCompActivty. App crashes.
**Log Cat is showing NoClassDefFoundError:**
Please Guide me in the Right way.
Thanks

Comment: Have you rebuild and clear project?

Comment: Try deleting the gen folder and then cleaning the project.

Comment: And Make sure you have same project build target for your project and every library project you have imported.

Comment: I did it guys but it's not working. :-(

Answer (score 1):

**`NoClassDefFoundError`** occurs when the source was successfully compiled, but at `runtime`, the required class files were not found. This may be something that can happen in the distribution or production of JAR files.

My Advise : **CLEAN AND REBUILD** Your Project .If not works Use Android Studio instead of Eclipse .

> [Android actionbar how to add supporting library v7 appcompat for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903521/android-actionbar-how-to-add-supporting-library-v7-appcompat-for-eclipse)

Comment: Amiya Thanks for the Advise.
 Regards: J.A.F

Comment: @JawadAziz Move ahead