# Cant run simple android program using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am studying Android now and I am really a newbie in this.
I am using Eclipse with Android. I already installed all the files under Android 5.0.1 (API 21) and also all the Tools. Then I try to create my simple "hello world example" but I got a lot of errors.

Here are my errors:

[image]

[image]

Can you help me with this?

Comment: You need to install api-23 in the SDK manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've added `AppCompat` on below picture:

[image]

That problem comes from AppCompat as you can see, seems like that library has a problem and you should follow this tutorial:

**Following are the steps:**

> Paste the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` that you have downloaded
>   in libs folder of your project.
>
> Right click on your project, select `Build Path -> Configure build
>   path.` Select `Library` Tab then Add Jar option and browse your
>   recently added v7 jar and click `OK`.

That should fix the problem.

[Android actionbar how to add supporting library v7 appcompat for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903521/android-actionbar-how-to-add-supporting-library-v7-appcompat-for-eclipse)

And i suggest you to use AndroidStudio.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. :)

Comment: Also, download the `23-Api` according to this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi5rW.png

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have some problems with styles, anyway i suggest to use Android Studio if you start from the beginning.

Comment: I already have android studio but how can I use my downloaded android sdk files from Eclipse? When I open Android Studio it still downloading.

Comment: Well it downloads some components you can configure your current SDK in the Preferences.