# failed to import supportv7 as lib

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to use `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in my project.So I imported project support v7 `appcompact` to `eclipse`.When I tried to add support v7 `appcompact` to my project as a lib,it didn't work.Shown as the picture,once I reopen `properties->android` it showed a cross.

```
Android->libarary->add
```

[image]
**errors shown**
[image]

I tried to add `support-v4` and `support-v7` `appcompact` jars in `support-v7` to my `project->libs`.Then I got no error.But when running application on my phone,it crashed.

> Logging:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;[crash log][3]

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse? Where is Gradle?

Comment: There's no support-v7 jar. You have to import the whole appcompat-v7 directory as a library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tks guys.I solved the problem by myself.

I removed appcompact project,reimported it and ticked off "copy projects into workspace" while importing.The red cross in properties->android->lib disappeared.And my application run normally on my device now.

By the way,you don't have to import appcompact.jar or support-v4.jar to your project.And you have to remove existing support-v4.jar in your project because this would lead to "multiple dex files define".

Is there anyone who can tell me why I cannot use project from a different folder?Tks:)

Answer (score -1):

1. Add support library from sdk manager

[image: sdk manger]

2.Go to your project in the navigator, right click on properties.

[image: properties]

3.Click add external jars.

4.Go to your ADT Bundle folder, go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs.

5.Select the file android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

6.Go to order and export and check the box next to your new jar.

7.Click ok.

For Detail: [link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved), [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903521/android-actionbar-how-to-add-supporting-library-v7-appcompat-for-eclipse)

Comment: TKs. I  had tried your suggestion,but still couldn't solve the problem. Error accored while running:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;