# Error while making Android Application Project in Eclipse Mars

Tags: android, eclipse

Im new to programming and am trying to make a game for Android. When I try to make a new Android Application Project, it lets me fill in the form and everything but when Eclipse is creating the project, I get this error: https://gyazo.com/1b875ce753ccf2aab85359b567abdba5

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar

Answer (score 0):

you need to import [appcompat-v7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903521/android-actionbar-how-to-add-supporting-library-v7-appcompat-for-eclipse) or check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emXRvufDoX0)

*updated* - another option - not use templates when create new project: means doesn't create activity, and ect via constructor. in this case you need to create it manualy. guess it simpliest that switch off appcompat.

btw. is better to use Android Studio, as for ex. latest adt not supported by eclipce

Comment: When I try to select a project in the library pane there are no projects

Comment: at first you need to import appcompat code to your workplase `Eclipse -> Import -> Existing Android Code into workspace.` select `<your sdk location> /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat ` but i guess you don't need this lib. try to create project without templates

Comment: But on the tutorial I am using it tells me to make the android app project

Comment: And in the android folder I don't have the support folder either

Comment: *Option 1*: 1) File->New->Android App Project. 2) [Fill Names] -> Next button 3) uncheck "Create Activity" -> Next button -> Finish 4) right click on src folder -> create new package-> enter your package name. 5) Create class  (Extends Activity) in this package. 6) declare class in manifest

*Option 2* remove lib but in this case you need to change code (extends from activity), changes styles, ect. so, i prefer option 1;

*Option 3* use Android studio - in all newest lessons AS is used.
Google cancel eclipce support. so there is some problems to use new libs, new adt, ect